# "No such file or directory" when opening file with scandir in PHP

Tags: php, xampp, scandir

I want to read the file with the longest file name in a folder called "json".

This is my PHP for that: (inside file "open.php")

```
<?php
// Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
// Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser
mb_http_output("UTF-8");

$files = scandir( __DIR__ . '/json', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newest_file = $files[0];
readfile($newest_file);
//$output = file_get_contents($newest_file);
//echo json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG); 
?>
```

The "json" folder is in the same directory as "open.php". When I run this on my server, I get as a response `false` (or a HTTP 500 error).

When I run this on XAMPP, I get: `Warning: readfile(thisone.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\open.php on line 15`.
I don't think it's an issue with permissions since I'm on Win 7. I checked both folder and file permissions and all users can "read".

**Question**: Why is PHP failing to open the file? It correctly finds the file I want, but right afterwards tells me there is "no such file".

---

*UPDATE:*
Running the following code:

```
// Tell PHP that we're using UTF-8 strings until the end of the script
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
// Tell PHP that we'll be outputting UTF-8 to the browser
mb_http_output("UTF-8");

$files = scandir( __DIR__ . '\\json', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
print_r($files);
$newest_file = $files[0];
print_r($newest_file);
readfile('/json/'.$newest_file); // corrected this, as @Jeff pointed out
```

I get as output:

```
Array ( [0] => thisone.json [1] => .. [2] => . ) thisone.json
Warning: readfile(/json/thisone.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\open.php on line 18
```

---

Related SO question: [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory/36577021#36577021)

Comment: because scandir returns and array with the _filenames_ - without the folder name. So `readfile('/json/'.$newest_file);` should be good.   ....and the error message actually says exactly that: `No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\open.php`, where you actually intended to search in `../test/json`

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the comment! I just made the alteration you suggested, but I got the same error as result

Comment: the error message is still the same (without the correct folder), so it might need to be `'\json\'.$newest_file`? ...or `'json\'`?

Comment: @Jeff Amazing!! Yes, that worked! But I used `'json\\'.` instead

Comment: @Jeff would you like to put it as an answer so I can pick it and close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) returns and array with the filenames - *without* the folder name.

But here `readfile($newest_file);` you didn't include the sub-folder (before your edit)

So include the desired folder in your path:

```
readfile('json\\'.$newest_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not related to the directory path, because in your state the path is probably correct. it depends on the file you are to read .
since you are try to read a `json` file you get this message but if you put any other file it will be read .
so you need to parse the `json` while reading 
like this

```
    $path = 'json/';
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $newest_file) {
    if ($newest_file === '.' or $newest_file === '..') continue;
    $data = json_decode(readfile($path.'/'.$newest_file));
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: a json file is still a simple text file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work, gets me the error: `Warning: readfile(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\open.php on line 19` . But I think @Jeff nailed it